# Handling if there is not enough memory available to start this thread c#

Tags: windows, multithreading, out-of-memory, c#-3.0

I have a system which starts a new thread with each request to the application.
if application received hundreds of requests there may be not enough memory available to start a new thread so it will throw an exception.

I would like to know an ideal mechanism to handle this kind of a situation.
like, if application is receiving lots of request then if there is not enough memory or number  of active threads reached the max then i will delay processing other requests.

but i have no idea how to implement this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution: Increase thread-pool limits. This is actually viable although out of fashion these days.

More thorough solution: Use a `SemaphoreSlim` to limit the number of concurrently asynchronously active requests. Make sure to wait asynchronously. If you wait synchronously you'll again burn a thread while waiting. After having waited asynchronously you can resume normal synchronous blocking processing. This requires only small code changes.

Most thorough solution: Implement your processing fully async. That way you never run out of threads.

Comment: i am not using background threads those are foreground threads so i dont think thread-pool will help. Anyway i have never used SemaphoreSlim. i will check that . thanks

Comment: OK, then start those threads with minimal stack size. Can easily save 4x memory over the default 1MB.

Comment: I am starting threads within a loop. Initially all the requests will be on a array then each will be executed on a new thread . can pls. elaborate more your statement "start those threads with minimal stack size". how we will get the min stack size and where i should mentioned it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=.net+thread+set+stack+size Be resourceful. Help yourself.

Comment: The C# version has nothing to do with thread size. I don't understand what you mean by queues and signaling (in fact how *could* I possibly understand from these two words?!). Please be more concrete.